# Bcrypt Password Truncation issue solution or Hashing Long Passwords with Bcrypt in Java?

Tags: java, ascii, bcrypt, sha512

In scenarios where passwords exceed the 72-byte limit of Bcrypt hashing, it becomes necessary to devise alternative approaches to ensure all input data is hashed without loss. One viable solution involves utilising the SHA-512 algorithm to initially hash the raw input, resulting in a hexadecimal string. This string is then converted to ASCII to truncate the input to less than 72 bytes, preserving data integrity. Subsequently, Bcrypt hashing can be applied to the truncated input to generate the desired hash value. Is this feasible in java. Whether this is correct approach or any other approach available.

````
MessageDigest sha512MD = null;
        sha512MD = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        String md512Output = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(sha512MD.digest(password.getBytes()));

        // ASCII conversion
        StringBuilder asciiOutput = new StringBuilder(70);
        for (int i = 0; i < md512Output.length(); i += 2) {
            String str = md512Output.substring(i, i + 2);
            asciiOutput.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        String asciiString = asciiOutput.toString();
        String hash = BCrypt.hashpw(asciiString, BCrypt.gensalt(bcryptLogRounds));```
````

Comment: Do you really need pwd longer then 72 bytes? If so you might want to use another algorithm instead of BCrypt. Using the hex is a proper way of doing things (see also https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html and then the fixes part).

Comment: [This answer on a related question on security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/184090) has some discussion of options to expand on the maximum. Personally I'd be very cautious with tweaking such a widely implemented algorithm without deep research and would rather live with that rather generous limit. If you need something more secure than a 72 byte password, then you should probably leave passwords behind entirely and switch to certificates or other non-human-memorable mechanisms anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum: really interesting article and that's exactly the kinds of issues that makes me reluctant to tweak existing systems like this (and should make most everyone reluctant as well, IMO).